# Getting the maximum common words in R

Tags: r, nlp

I have data of the form:

```
ID       A1    A2    A3   ...   A100
1      john    max  karl  ...   kevin
2      kevin   bosy lary  ...   rosy
3      karl   lary  bosy  ...   hale
.
.
.
10000  isha   john  lewis ...   dave
```

I want to get one ID for each ID such that both of them have maximum number of common attributes(A1,A2,..A100)

How can I do this in R ?
Edit: Let's call the output a MatchId:

```
ID      MatchId
1        70
2        4000
.
.
10000   3000
```

Comment: It;s not clear what is your desired output. Can you show an example?

Comment: Your edit isn't corresponding the provided data set. It is better to create, lets say, 15 rows data set and provide desired result that corresponds to the provided data set (not your real one which don't have).

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of ties?

Comment: @hrbrmstr take the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets what you're looking for:

```
library(dplyr)

# make up some data

set.seed(1492)
rbind_all(lapply(1:15, function(i) {
  x <- cbind.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, i, t(sample(LETTERS, 10)))
  colnames(x) <- c("ID", sprintf("A%d", 1:10))
  x
})) -> dat

print(dat)

## Source: local data frame [15 x 11]
## 
##    ID A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8 A9 A10
## 1   1  H  F  E  C  B  A  R  J  Z   N
## 2   2  Q  P  E  M  L  Z  C  G  V   Y
## 3   3  Q  J  D  N  B  T  L  K  G   Z
## 4   4  D  Y  U  F  V  O  I  C  A   W
## 5   5  T  Z  D  I  J  F  R  C  B   S
## 6   6  Q  D  H  U  P  V  O  E  R   N
## 7   7  C  L  I  M  E  K  N  S  X   Z
## 8   8  M  J  S  E  N  O  F  Y  X   I
## 9   9  R  H  V  N  M  T  Q  X  L   S
## 10 10  Q  H  L  Y  B  W  S  M  P   X
## 11 11  M  N  J  K  B  G  S  X  V   R
## 12 12  W  X  A  H  Y  D  N  T  Q   I
## 13 13  K  H  V  J  D  X  Q  W  A   U
## 14 14  M  U  F  H  S  T  W  Z  O   N
## 15 15  G  B  U  Y  E  L  A  Q  W   O

# get commons

rbind_all(lapply(1:15, function(i) {
  rbind_all(lapply(setdiff(1:15, i), function(j) {
    data.frame(id1=i,
               id2=j,
               common=length(intersect(c(t(dat[i, 2:11])),
                                       c(t(dat[j, 2:11])))))
  }))
})) -> commons

commons %>%
  group_by(id1) %>%
  top_n(1, common) %>%
  filter(row_number()==1) %>%
  select(ID=id1, MatchId=id2)

## Source: local data frame [15 x 2]
## Groups: ID
## 
##    ID MatchId
## 1   1       5
## 2   2       7
## 3   3       5
## 4   4      12
## 5   5       1
## 6   6       9
## 7   7       8
## 8   8       7
## 9   9      10
## 10 10       9
## 11 11       9
## 12 12      13
## 13 13      12
## 14 14       8
## 15 15       2
```

Comment: what filter() is doing ?

Comment: taking only the first element from the computed "top n" of the group. similar to `head(df, 1)` of a normal data frame

Answer (score 2):

Using similar data as provided by @hrbrmstr

```
set.seed(1492)
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:15, function(i) {
  x <- cbind.data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE, i, t(sample(LETTERS, 10)))
  colnames(x) <- c("ID", sprintf("A%d", 1:10))
  x
}))
```

You could achieve the same using base R only

```
Res <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(dat)), 
              function(x) apply(dat[-1], 1, 
              function(y) length(intersect(dat[x, -1], y))))
diag(Res) <- -1
cbind(dat[1], MatchId = max.col(Res, ties.method = "first"))
#    ID MatchId
# 1   1       5
# 2   2       7
# 3   3       5
# 4   4      12
# 5   5       1
# 6   6       9
# 7   7       8
# 8   8       7
# 9   9      10
# 10 10       9
# 11 11       9
# 12 12      13
# 13 13      12
# 14 14       8
# 15 15       2
```

Comment: here apply() is doing the work of setdiff(), isn't it ?

Comment: If you referring to @hrbrmstrs solution, I didn't go thru it. I think he is using  `setdiff` in order to avoid comparing same IDs. I'm not doing it. I'm comparing everything and then I'm running `diag(Res) <- -1` in order to make sure that same IDs will get the lowest values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the requirement is to obtain the maximum number of common attributes for each ID.

Frequency tables can be obtained using `table()` and recursively in `lapply()`, assuming that ID column is unique - slight modification is necessary if not (`unique(df$ID)` rather than `df$ID` in `lapply()`). The maximum frequencies can be taken and, if there is a tie, only the first one is chosen. Finally they are combined by `do.call()`.

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "
ID       A1    A2    A3   A100
1      john    max  karl  kevin
2      kevin   bosy lary  rosy
3      karl   lary  bosy  hale
10000  isha   john  lewis dave")

do.call(rbind, lapply(df$ID, function(x) {
  tbl <- table(unlist(df[df$ID == x, 2:ncol(df)]))
  data.frame(ID = x, MatchId = tbl[tbl == max(tbl)][1])
}))

#         ID MatchId
#john      1       1
#kevin     2       1
#karl      3       1
#isha  10000       1
```